# Context Free Grammar to Chomsky Normal Form Help

Tags: automata, context-free, chomsky-hierarchy

I am trying to convert the following CFG to CNF:

```
S -> ABS | ε
A -> BSBa | a
B -> Ba | a
```

The finally result looks like this:

```
S -> AS’ | AB
S’ -> BS
A -> S’B’ |BB’ | X
B’ -> BX
X -> a
Y -> b
B -> BX | XY
```

I am fairly new to chomsky normal form, so can anyone verify that I did this right?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: In computing ChNF as an exercise perhaps the final result is not really important. What really matters is the sequence of steps that you took. That said, $A \to X$ is not in the right form. Also: your original grammar cannot generate words with the letter $b$.